# How to check if a specific script element is async or defer with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Hi I try to find out which script are having async set using Puppeteer.

So my idea is to look for script tags with a specific src set, than get the full html of the tag and extract async there

I started with something like this

```
const pattern = 'script[src*="'+url+'"]'
const text = await page.$(pattern);
```

but failed. Also with this (thescript.js) is in the html for sure

```
const text = await page.$('script[src*="thescript.js"]');
```

I get some huge json as a result and tested

```
text.innerText
test.innerHTML
```

but these where all empty.

Comment: have you been able to solve the issue in the meantime @Tobi?

Answer (score 0):

As a simplier and "more puppeteer" solution you can use `.getAttribute('src')` to identify the script that you need, then `await page.evaluate(el => el.async, (await page.$$('script'))[i])` to check if it is **async** OR `await page.evaluate(el => el.defer, (await page.$$('script'))[i])` to check if it is **defer**.

An example where all scripts iterated over and checked if they are async:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function fn() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://example-with-script-tags.com')

  const scriptsOnPage = await page.$$eval('script', el => el.map(o => o.getAttribute('src')))

  for (const [i, src] of scriptsOnPage.entries()) {
    const async = await page.evaluate(el => el.async, (await page.$$('script'))[i])
    console.log(src + ' is async: ' + async)
  }

  await browser.close()
}
fn()
```

**Output:**

```
fn1() is async: true
fn2() is async: true
fn3() is async: true
fn4() is async: false
```

You can test the scripts in Chrome devtools *Console* tab as well with:

**1st script:**

- `$$('script')[0].attributes.src`
- `$$('script')[0].async`

**2nd script:**

- `$$('script')[1].attributes.src`
- `$$('script')[1].async`

  etc.